# Quart Python Error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string'

Tags: python, html, web, discord, quart

I code a discord panel and I would like to put a text in another variable with quart python:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename=f'assets/IconDiscord/{0}.png'.format(connect))}}"
```

maos I get this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string'
```

how can I insert the contents of the variable in the image url?

Comment: Do you mean this `f'assets/IconDiscord/{0}.png'.format(connect)` to be both a `f` string (f prefixed) and to use the `.format` argument? I'd use `'assets/IconDiscord/{0}.png'.format(connect)`